# JS Folder not reading in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

My wordpress is not picking up my js folder. Anyone might know why?
My function.php file looks like this:

```
<?php

function lcc_files() {
  wp_enqueue_script('main-lcc-js', get_theme_file_uri('/js/scripts-bundled.js'), NULL, '1.0', true);
  wp_enqueue_style('lcc_main_styles', get_stylesheet_uri());
  
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'lcc_files');

function lcc_features() {
  add_theme_support('title-tag');
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'lcc_features');
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that the footer of the Wordpress site was not set up yet.
As soon as I set the footer up, the Javascript worked.
this is why no answers helped, no one actually suggested that.